# Is there a counter for part-time jobs?

Tags: counters

I needed to translate the sentence "Mary has three part-time jobs." What's the counter for "jobs" (*baito*, *shigoto*)?

Also, how do I say that "I organized my room"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. You can use ふたつ、みっつ... for counting アルバイト or 仕事:

> メアリーは、３つ(アル)バイト/仕事を[掛]{か}け[持]{も}ちしている。
>   or (アル)バイト/仕事を３つ掛け持ちしている。
>   メアリーは、仕事を３つ持っている。
>   メアリーは、バイトを３つやっている。etc...

Alternatively, you can also use ２か所で、３か所で... (at 2 places, 3 places...):

> メアリーは、[３]{さん}か[所]{しょ}で(アル)バイト/仕事(を)している。

2. How about:

> 部屋を[片]{かた}づけた。/ 部屋の片づけをした。
>   or
>   部屋を[整理]{せいり}した。/ 部屋を整理[整頓]{せいとん}した。

Comment: 1. So hitotsu futatsu and nika sanka are used whenever the counted has no counter of its own?

Comment: @user1998628 The counter in ２か所【しょ】 is not か, but か所【しょ】. You can use 一つ【ひとつ】・二つ【ふたつ】 for things that don't have a counter of their own, but [一か所]【いっかしょ】・[二か所]【にかしょ】 are exclusively for places (hence 所, which means "place").

Comment: I see, I confused it a bit there since Genki II teaches a specific way of counting. Thank you for all the answers :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess "Mary has three part-time jobs." would be translated into "Mary はパートを3件{けん}掛{か}け持{も}ちしている。"

(I am not inclined toward the use of パート to indicate part-time jobs, though
.)

As for "I organized my room," I guess @Choko's answer "部屋を片づけた" will do.

Comment: I have always understood it as 仕事 - Full-Time Work,　パート - Part-Time Work,　（アル）バイト - Casual Work

Comment: All I can say is the distinction between パート and （アル）バイト is not so strict or "rigourous" as one may want it to be. Here is an opinion -> http://framgang.net/archives/1730.html.

Comment: When I consulted Hello Work (MoHLW), they have made the distinction between both パート and バイト . Even your link makes an attempt at a difference when considering working hours (by law a バイト is only required to work 2 hours a shift) which wasn't in your link. The difference a lot of companies make seems to be the difference between 正社員 and 派遣社員 combined with working hours. バイト are flexible non-permanent, contract staff working 2+ hours a shift any time of the day. パート（タイム） can be either non-permanent, contract staff or permanent staff usually working during normal business hours...

Comment: ...(with the exclusion of some contract staff which may be contracted to work after hours) and who have hours less than or equal to a full time staff member. Then you have 仕事 or フルタイム which consists of usually working during normal business hours as a permanent employee. Also weighing in to the difference is termination. Being terminated when doing a バイト can be an instantaneous firing with no additional compensation whereas a パート usually gets some restitution for being fired according to either their contract or their companies rules.

Comment: Legally, full-time workers get 3 months of job seeking help as well as 1 -3 months pay as a severance (there are also additional bonuses and protection full-time staff get upon severance not listed here).

Comment: @The Wandering Coder: Wow, an extensive research, indeed.